# How to add the environment variables to the android Runtime.getRuntime().exec command?

Tags: java, android, linux, bash, shell

There's an issue when I run the android `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` method.

I have a native binary file to be run on android and I start it with the java method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`. But running this native binary file requires the addition of an environment variable. So I execute this command:

`envSetCmd = {"sh", "-c", "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="+excBinFilepath+":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"}.`

It doesn't work when I check the environment variable with the command: 
`sh`, `-c`, `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I think the reason is that when I set the environment variables I start a shell and when I check it with the command "echo" another shell was started. So the environment variables didn't work in the shell I check it.

I think there are two ways to solve this issue. The one is that running two commands in one shell. So I tried to use the command:

```
{"sh", "-c", "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="+excBinFilepath+":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "-c", "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH"}.
```

Unfortunately it is illegal. The other is that I add the environment variables to the android user startup files. I tried to echo the `$PATH`, and I see the `/system/bin/` and other path was loaded at the startup of android.

So I think there must be a file just like the `~/.bashrc` in linux which could set the users' environment.

Any one could give me some clues about the ways I listed above? By the way, I shouldn't root the phone!

Answer (score 0):

try to execute whatever you need to execute with env:

```
{"env", "LD_LIBRARY_PATH="+excBinFilepath, "yourCmd"}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i failed to try it. i know that this command works well in linux shell. but i checked the commands supported by adb shell and the "env" is not included in it. it shows that "/system/bin/sh: env: not found". do you have succeeded to run this command? and could you please me some advice further?